# Why does this regex fails to check accurately?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex method which does the matches in 3 stages for a given string. But for some reason the `Regex` fails to check some of the things. As per whatever knowledge I have gained by working they seem to be correct. Can someone please correct me what am I doing wrong here?

I have the following code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String identifier = "urn:abc:de:xyz:234567.1890123";

        if (identifier.matches("^urn:abc:de:xyz:.*")) {
            System.out.println("Match ONE");

            if (identifier.matches("^urn:abc:de:xyz:[0-9]{6,12}.[0-9]{1,7}.*")) {
                System.out.println("Match TWO");

                if (identifier.matches("^urn:abc:de:xyz:[0-9]{6,12}.[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,20}$")) {
                    System.out.println("Match Three");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Ideally, this code should generate the output

```
Match ONE
Match TWO
Match Three
```

Only when the `identifier = "urn:abc:de:xyz:234567.1890123.abd12"` but it provides the same output event if the identifier does not match the regex such as for the following inputs:

```
"urn:abc:de:xyz:234567.1890123"
"urn:abc:de:xyz:234567.1890ANC"
"urn:abc:de:xyz:234567.1890123"
"urn:abc:de:xyz:234567.1890ACB.123"
```

I am not understanding why is it allowing the Alphanumeric characters after the `.` and also it does not care about the characters after the second `.`.

I would like my `Regex` to check that the string has the following format:

1. String starts with `urn:abc:de:xyz:`
2. Then it has the numbers [0-9] which range from 6 to 12 (`234567`).
3. Then it has the decimal point `.`
4. Then it has the numbers [0-9] which range from 1 to 7 (`1890123`)
5. Then it has the decimal point `.`.
6. Finally it has the alphanumeric character and spcial character which range from 1 to 20 (ABC123.-_12).

This is an valid string for my regex: `urn:abc:de:xyz:234567.1890123.ABC123.-_12`

This is an invalid string for my regex as it misses the elements from point 6:
`urn:abc:de:xyz:234567.1890123`

This is also an invalid string for my regex as it misses the elements from point 4 (it has ABC instead of decimal numbers).
`urn:abc:de:xyz:234567.1890ABC.ABC123.-_12`

Comment: See [the regex reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). `.` not only matches the dot character. It matches almost everything.

Comment: Because `.` has special meaning in regex. That’s why your `.*` at the end works - it means (almost) any character 0 or more times.

Comment: @Sweeper How can I ensure there is a `.` and the required characters in my String? How can I modify my `regex` matching expression to check for these things?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for the response. How can I modify it to make it work and check for the things I need?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are checking for... What exactly do you want to match, and what do you not want to match?

Comment: @Sweeper I have modified the question and added the constraint which I am looking to add to my regex. Please let me know if you are able to understand and help me with this.

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/SlM7E6/1) what you want?

Comment: Yup Thanks thats working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the regex:

- `[0-9]{6,12}.[0-9]{1,7}` matches 6 to 12 digits followed by *any* character followed by 1 to 7 digits

To match a dot, it needs to be escaped. Try this:

```
^urn:abc:de:xyz:[0-9]{6,12}\.[0-9]{1,7}\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,20}$
```

Comment: But if I escape the `.` character then it would not check if there is a `.` character or not right?

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 No, it would only match exactly the dot, if you escape it. Otherwise it would match any non-newline character.

Comment: The backslash-dot sequence does match a dot. After matching the dot it can be removed between the last square brackets, if no more dots need be be matched.

Answer (score 0):

This will match with any number of dot alphanum at the end of the string as your examples:

```
^urn:abc:de:xyz:\d{6,12}\.\d{1,7}(?:\.[\w-]{1,20})+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/1xedxH/1)